# Build Adaptive card using Microsoft C# library or JSON Schema?

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, adaptive-cards

I am new to building webchat bot. I have one built one webchat bot in C# using the Microsoft Bot framework. I now need to add an Adaptive card to the app, my basic question is - Should I build the adaptive card using the Microsfot.AdaptiveCard library and the C# code or using the JSON schema? The reason for this question is I should be able to reuse the webchat bot code to any other platform/channel like Facebook, Slack, Apple iMessenger etc. and not limit to C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right -- sticking to JSON Schema is a good idea and will ensure that when you're using cards in other channels you don't have to convert & save from the C# Adaptive Cards library to a format the channels can read. In case you haven't seen these docs yet, here are the [getting started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/getting-started) docs for Adaptive Cards, and you can use the [Schema Explorer](http://adaptivecards.io/explorer/) and [Visualizer](http://adaptivecards.io/visualizer/index.html?hostApp=Bot%20Framework%20WebChat) to help build your cards.

This is irrelevant to you if if you're using JSON Schema, but to anyone who decides to use the AC Library, please note: The Adaptive Cards package has been updated from Microsoft.AdaptiveCards to AdaptiveCards, as well as a few other [breaking changes](https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/pull/633).